# Expanding universe via vaccuum?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

I was wondering if anyone looked at the expanding model of the universe in terms of a vacuum pulling the universe out rather than an explosion pushing the universe outwards? Or explain why this model would not work?

Comment: could you precise "pulling the universe" ? do you mean that the total size remains constant with a decreasing c ?

Comment: Vacuums don't pull.  What might appear to be a pull is the result a pressure gradient.  It's always a "push".

Comment: The second question (*...worthy of thought?*) seems to be an opinion-based question, so I'm removing that. I think the rest of the question is okay.

Comment: [The universe isn't expanding outwards from a point](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point). There is no vacuum outside the universe. In fact the universe has no *outside* at all.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot look at the expansion of the universe -- or say the big bang -- as being comparable to an explosion. Every point in space drifts away from every other point in space. This is different to an explosion, where you have a real center. The latter aspect is missing -- or say different -- when you look at the expansion of the universe. Here you don't have a center. I think, this is an aspect you should keep in mind, when asking this question. Hence, the vacuum pulling inside would also require a center towards it is pulling, in my opinion.

Best,

Markus

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if anyone looked at the expanding model of the universe in terms of a vacuum pulling the universe out rather than an explosion pushing the universe outwards? Or explain why this model would not work?

In the classical Newtonian mechanics the vacuum is simply a medium that does not oppose any resistance. In order to travel through vacuum a material object (a celestial body, for example) needs an initial speed or a force acting on it.

The apparent suction of vacuum is simply an illusion.